# Mongo Graph Lookup Query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

My mongo collection name is home and whose having the following documents in it.

```
[{

    "title": "Java",
    "uid": "1",
    "_metadata": {
        "references": [{
            "asssetuid": 10
        }]
    }
},
{

    "title": "Servlet",
    "uid": "2",
    "_metadata": {
        "references": [{
                "uid": "1"
            },
            {
                "asssetuid": 11
            }
        ]
    }
},
{

    "title": "JSP",
    "uid": "3",
    "_metadata": {
        "references": [{
            "uid": "2"
        }]
    }
}
```

]

I want results like

```
{
"uid": 1,
"_metadata": {
    "references": [{
            "asssetuid": 10
        }, {
            "uid": "2"
        },
        {
            "asssetuid": 11
        },
        {
            "uid": "3"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

as per we need full hierarch of a document whose uid is 1.

How we can get this result. is any way in graph lookup query to get the required result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup), it gives you the power to recursively search for matches which is what you're looking for:

```
db.home.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      uid: "1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$graphLookup": {
      "from": "home",
      "startWith": "$uid",
      "connectFromField": "uid",
      "connectToField": "_metadata.references.uid",
      "as": "matches"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      uid: 1,
      _metadata: {
        refrences: {
          $map: {
            input: "$matches",
            as: "match",
            in: {
              uid: "$$match.uid"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8hHaZ321ofM)

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it is working fine. but I have updated the question added one more field into references. So how I can get give result kindly help me there